# Multiple Users accessing IMAP mailboxes

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007, imap

I have what I think an unusual setup, I have a few mailboxes setup, orders, info and qa. These mailboxes are setup to allow IMAP, I then have at least 4 users having constant Outlook access to these IMAP mailboxes (qa has 8 users). Also all these users are accessing these IMAP boxes internally.

I want a different method of multiple users accessing these mailboxes preferably not using IMAP. I'm open to suggestions as this would have to be put forward to the board for approval.

I know I have been very brief so ask me if you want me to elaborate on anything in particular.

Comment: Is there some issue that IMAP has or feature that it lacks that you're trying to get with this new method?

Comment: Not really, I just don't really want to be using IMAP at all.

Comment: POP or IMAP is all what you may have.

Comment: "I don't like IMAP" is a terrible reason to do something.  As they say, if it ain't broke, don't fix it!  If there's a specific problem you're trying to solve please let us know and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: I want certain users to have more control of the mailbox for a start.

Comment: Are you currently using Exchange? Or have you tagged this exchange because you want to move to that? If your already using Exchange you can give permission to these users to access these mailboxes in Exchange and connect to them using MAPI in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 2 options:

- Setup public folders for each of
  the mailboxes and have mail delivered
  in there
- Setup another exchange
  user, deliver mail there and share
  folders with other users

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using IMAP for this? Why not just have the users extra add the extra mailboxes to their Outlook?

Comment: I think thats probably the way forward. Can multiple users access the same mailbox and can I assign certain privelages to certain users?

Comment: Yes and yes. It's how we share accounts.